# Stored Procedure to Insert comma seperated values as multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please help me in creating a stored procedure which accepts comma separated values and inserts as multiple rows.

So one parameter `@Name` will contain values A,B,C and the other parameter `@Id` will contain values as 1,2,3

The table values after insertion should be as below:

```
Name     Id  
------------
A         1 
A         2 
A         3 
B         1 
B         2 
B         3 
C         1 
C         2 
C         3
```

How can I write a stored procedure that can insert the comma-separated values as shown above. Also, If the table already consists of a Name,id pair for example, if A,2 is already there in the table, then it should not insert.

I am using SQL Server 2005. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: A constraint for uniqueness on `(Name,ID)` should keep the table clean.

Comment: Check that: [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond When TVPs Do Not Cut it](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @var1   VARCHAR(100)='A,B,C';
DECLARE @var2   VARCHAR(100)='1,2,3';

WITH rep1(name, delim) AS
(
    SELECT @var1 name, ',' delim

    UNION ALL

    SELECT LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(delim, name, 1) - 1) name, delim
    FROM rep1
    WHERE (CHARINDEX(delim, name, 1) > 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT RIGHT(name, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(delim, name, 1)) name, delim
    FROM rep1
    WHERE (CHARINDEX(delim, name, 1) > 0)
)
,rep2(id, delim) AS
(
    SELECT @var2 id, ',' delim

    UNION ALL

    SELECT LEFT(id, CHARINDEX(delim, id, 1) - 1) id, delim
    FROM rep2
    WHERE (CHARINDEX(delim, id, 1) > 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT RIGHT(id, LEN(id) - CHARINDEX(delim, id, 1)) id, delim
    FROM rep2
    WHERE (CHARINDEX(delim, id, 1) > 0)
)
INSERT #table
(Name
,ID)
SELECT
 r1.name
,r2.id
FROM rep1 r1
CROSS JOIN rep2 r2
LEFT JOIN #table t
ON r2.id=t.id
AND t.name=r1.name
WHERE (CHARINDEX(r1.delim, r1.name, 1) = 0)
AND (CHARINDEX(r2.delim, r2.id, 1) = 0)
AND t.name IS NULL
ORDER BY r1.name
,r2.id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here we are sepearting Comma Seperated into rows**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Temp

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NewTemp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #NewTemp

    Declare  @Testdata table ( name Varchar(max), Data varchar(max))
    insert @Testdata select 'A', '1,2,3'
    insert @Testdata select 'B', '1,2,3'
    insert @Testdata select 'C', '1,2'
    insert @Testdata select 'A', '1,2,3,4'
    insert @Testdata select 'C', '1,2,3,4,5'

    ;with tmp(name, DataItem, Data) as (
    select name, LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1),
        STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
    from @Testdata
    union all
    select name, LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1),
        STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
    from tmp
    where Data > ''
    )
```

**Then Inserting into Temp Table**

```
select DISTINCT name, DataItem INTO #Temp
from    tmp WHERE   EXISTS (Select DISTINCT name,DataItem from tmp)
order by name
```

**Here we are controlling entry of Duplicates we can observe combination won't repeat like (A,1),(B,1)Even though they are multiple**

```
CREATE TABLE #NewTemp(name Varchar(max), Data varchar(max))
INSERT INTO #NewTemp (name,Data)
Select name,DataItem from #Temp

Select * FROM #NewTemp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go and create one user defined functions for splitting the comma separated values into rows as below 
How this function will work and more on it can be found [here](http://everysolution.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/udf-to-split-a-delimited-string-and-return-it-as-a-table/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
 @RowData nvarchar(2000),
 @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
 Id int identity(1,1),
 Data nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
 Declare @Cnt int
 Set @Cnt = 1
 DECLARE @index INT
 SET @index = Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)
 While (@index>0)
 Begin
 Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
  Select
 Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,@index-1)))

 Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,@index+1,len(@RowData))
 Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
 SET @index = Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)
 End

 Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
 Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

 Return
END
```

Once this function is created, you can use it for your requirement as below

```
declare @Name VARCHAR(30) 
declare @Id VARCHAR(30) 

SET @Name = 'A,B,C'
SET @Id = '1,2,3'

select A.Data,B.Data FROM dbo.Split(@name,',') A ,dbo.Split(@id,',') B
```